# Gender in Kentucky marriages

Tags: united-states

In Kentucky, when two people want a marriage license, does the license require a determination of gender?

If it does, what evidence (if any) must the parties present to establish their genders?

Comment: @nomenagentis: Why the rewrite? Just curious.

Comment: @nomenagentis: Okay. Just curious. Thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated. +1